# Grep Spellchecker

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I am trying to write a simple shell script that takes a text file as input and checks all non-punctuated words against a dictionary (english.txt). It should return all non-matching (misspelled) words. I am using grep but it does not seem to successfully match all the lines in english.txt. I have included my code below.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 |
tr ' \t' '\n\n' |
sed -e "/'/d" |
tr -d '[:punct:]' |
tr -cd '[:alpha:]\n' |
sed -e "/^$/d" |
grep -v -i -w -f english.txt
```

Comment: you need a loop (one check per word). but better use `aspell`...

Comment: Doesn't the -f flag check each line in the dictionary?

Comment: When you say it "does not seem to successfully match all the lines," what exactly do you mean?  Does it print any correctly spelled words?  Fail to print any misspelled words?  Something else?

Comment: So my script works correctly on a small file size for english.txt, but once I feed it the full dictionary, many lines are not matched and therefore correct words are printed as misspelled words